# Is there a way to display category items in categories listing

Tags: subcategories, contact

I am writing a theme for our team website and am currently using the categor**y** listing from `com_contact` to display a list of our team members. All members are in a single category called "Teammembers". We have an organizational structure, therefore I used the sorting fields on the contacts to sort them by organizational layers, as seen below:

[image: Teammembers sorted by organizational layer but in single category]

I want to take this a step further, showing the titles of the organizational layers, which led me to the conclusion that I'm better off using a categor**ies** listing instead, splitting the members into separate subcategories, and showing the contents (i.e. contact items) inside of the subcategories in the top view below their respective subcategory titles (see below).

[image: Teammembers split into subcategories showing in categories view]

Is there any way to render the items contained inside of all subcategories in a parent category? As far as I can tell I can only render out the subcategory (titles) themselves and not their children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it myself. I modified my `com_contact` `category` `default_children` template to load another template part (called it `catitems`):

```
<?php if ($child->numitems > 0 ) :
    $this->children[$child->id] = $child->getChildren();
    $this->category = $child;
    $this->maxLevel--;
    echo $this->loadTemplate('catitems');
    $this->category = $child->getParent();
    $this->maxLevel++;
endif; ?>
```

In `default_catitems` I included a database query to the `contact_details` table to gather all contacts with the current category's ID:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory
::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('name', 'alias', 'con_position', 'email_to', 'telephone', 'fax', 'image', 'published', 'access', 'id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__contact_details'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' = '. $db->quote($cat_id));
$query->order('sortname2 ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
```

Sorting is done by `sortname2` which contains the contact names with last name first. Pretty ugly to have that hardcoded here, but I'll fix that later.

Finally I iterate over `$results` to generate my contact list in the subcategory, which is basically a clone of the `default_items` template with minor modifications. Depending on the contents of the contact list, one might have to generate `$item->slug` in each loop iteration (is not part of the `contact_details` table):

```
<?php $item->slug=$item->id .':'. $item->alias; ?>
```

Comment: Hello @RivEpica and welcome to JSE. That's all good you have done, just you should do it in template override, because core changes might be overwritten on next Joomla upgrade. I am sure you can find enough informaton on template override here on JSE.

Comment: @MirkoMikan Thank you! You're right, I wasn't too verbose about it but I actually *did* it in template override. It's just the "default" contact category template for the theme I'm developing. But it is part of the template, not in `./components/com_contact/views/category/tmpl/`.

Comment: Well, great then...

Comment: User @SNeppers has asked "Hope it is not to much to ask, but could you please show more in detail how you accomplished this? I am having trouble to find out what to use and modifiy from the default_items.php into the default_catitems.php. I would be so thankful."

Answer (score 0):

For `Category view` in file `default_children.php` after tag `<li...` add code:

```
    <?php

    // Get Category Model data
    $categoryModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Category', 'ContactModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    $categoryModel->setState('category.id', $child->id);
    $categoryModel->setState('list.ordering', 'a.name');
    $categoryModel->setState('list.direction', 'asc');
    $categoryModel->setState('filter.published', 1);

    $contacts = $categoryModel->getItems();

    ?>
```

For `Custom Fields` add first line after previus code, and in cycle get custom field for each contact:

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
foreach($contacts as $contactItem) {
    $currentContFields[] = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_contact.contact', $contactItem, true);
}
```